# Trabalhando com Array no PHP

Tags: php, array

Gostaria de saber como proceder para conseguir o resultado abaixo em `PHP`.

A saída que tenho hoje é:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "0000000009999999"
    [1] => "20181209"
    [2] => "000000"
    [3] => "REM BASICA"
    [4] => "0.00"
    [5] => "C"

)
Array
(
    [0] => "0000000009999999"
    [1] => "20181209"
    [2] => "000000"
    [3] => "CRED JUROS"
    [4] => "0.02"
    [5] => "C"

)
Array
(
    [0] => "0000000009999999"
    [1] => "20181210"
    [2] => "102109"
    [3] => "CRED TEV"
    [4] => "70.00"
    [5] => "C"

)
```

O que eu preciso é:

```
[0]

    [Conta] => "0000000009999999"
    [Data] => "20181209"
    [Cod] => "000000"
    [Historico] => "REM BASICA"
    [Valor] => "0.00"
    [Op] => "C"

[1]

    [Conta] => "0000000009999999"
    [Data] => "20181209"
    [Cod] => "000000"
    [Historico] => "REM BASICA"
    [Valor] => "0.00"
    [Op] => "C"


[2]

    [Conta] => "0000000009999999"
    [Data] => "20181209"
    [Cod] => "000000"
    [Historico] => "REM BASICA"
    [Valor] => "0.00"
    [Op] => "C"
```

Answer (score 5):

Outra forma de obter o mesmo resultado é usar um foreach com um `array_combine()` essa função criar um novo array sendo que o primeiro argumentos defines as chaves e o segundo os respectivo valores, isso feito de posicional ou seja o indice zero do array de chaves deve ser o valor desejado do array de valores.

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    array("0000000009999999","20181209","000000","REM BASICA","0.00","C"),
    array("0000000009999999","20181209","000000","CRED JUROS","0.02","C")
);

$chaves = array('Conta', 'Data', 'Cod', 'Historico', 'Valor', 'Op');

$novo = array();

foreach($arr as $item){
    $novo[] = array_combine($chaves, $item);
}

print_r($novo);
```

[Exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/sNXo7O)

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Conta] => 0000000009999999
            [Data] => 20181209
            [Cod] => 000000
            [Historico] => REM BASICA
            [Valor] => 0.00
            [Op] => C
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Conta] => 0000000009999999
            [Data] => 20181209
            [Cod] => 000000
            [Historico] => CRED JUROS
            [Valor] => 0.02
            [Op] => C
        )

)
```

Comment: legal, essa forma complementa mais a respostas. +1

Answer (score 4):

Com uma simples função é fácil resolver esse problema, ***exemplo***:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    array("0000000009999999","20181209","000000","REM BASICA","0.00","C"),
    array("0000000009999999","20181209","000000","CRED JUROS","0.02","C")
);

function transforme($array) 
{
    $array_new = array();
    foreach($array as $values)
    {
        $array_copy = array();
        foreach ($values as $key => $value) 
        {
            switch ($key) {
                case 0:     
                    $array_copy['Conta'] = $value;  
                    break;
                case 1: 
                    $array_copy['Data'] = $value;           
                    break;
                case 2:             
                    $array_copy['Cod'] = $value;
                    break;
                case 3:             
                    $array_copy['Historico'] = $value;
                    break;
                case 4:             
                    $array_copy['Valor'] = $value;
                    break;
                case 5:             
                    $array_copy['Op'] = $value;
                    break;
            }
        }
        $array_new[] = $array_copy;
    }
    return $array_new;
}

print_r(transforme($array));
```

<sub>[Exemplo Ideone](https://ideone.com/SzZvRG)</sub>

Como funciona:

É um `array` é simples onde cada posição é um número iniciando de 0 até o 5, então cada posição é um campo assim especificado e a lógica vai assim até acabar a última posição do `array`. Vale lembrar que em grosso modo se todas as posições tiverem o mesmo layout, esse `script` vai funcionar sem problema.

Essa forma proposta é mais básica possível, lembrando que o `PHP` possui outras funções que podem simplificar o código, mas, não deixa claro (ou legível), que é um outra *briga no mundo dos desenvolvedores*.